# Possible to use brace (permutation) and array expansion simultaneously?

Tags: bash, shell-script, brace-expansion, shell-builtin

Bash's `{}` brace expansion syntax allows for creating easy permutations

```
# echo {b,c,d}{a,e,i,o,u}
ba be bi bo bu ca ce ci co cu da de di do du
```

However it's not clear to me if/how it's possible to use this along with arrays except in very awkward use of `$()` `echo` and `eval`

Is there a simple way to use arrays with curly brace (permutation) expansion?

For example sake, imagine something like (which does not work of course):

```
CONS=( b c d )
VOWEL=( a e i o u )

echo {${CONS[@]}}{${VOWEL[@]}}
```

Comment: it's working in `GNU bash, version 4.2.24`  Output `root@router:~# echo {${CONS[@]}}{${VOWEL[@]}}
{b c d}{a e i o u}.` if you want different then let us know ..
`

Comment: @RahulPatil the OP wants `ba be bi bo bu ca ce ci co cu da de di do du`.

Answer (score 12):

You might use eval with `IFS=,; "${array[*]}"` (which joins the values with commas) or just two for loops:

```
$ CONS=(b c d);VOWEL=(a e i o u)
$ IFS=,;eval echo "{${CONS[*]}}{${VOWEL[*]}}"
ba be bi bo bu ca ce ci co cu da de di do du
$ for c in "${CONS[@]}";do for v in "${VOWEL[@]}";do echo "$c$v";done;done|paste -sd' ' -
ba be bi bo bu ca ce ci co cu da de di do du
```

Answer (score 9):

It's possible with `zsh`:

```
$ CONS=( b c d )
$ VOWEL=( a e i o u )
$ echo $^CONS$^VOWEL
ba be bi bo bu ca ce ci co cu da de di do du
```

Or [`es`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_%28Unix_shell%29):

```
; VOWEL=( a e i o u )
; CONS=( b c d )
; echo $VOWEL^$CONS
ab ac ad eb ec ed ib ic id ob oc od ub uc ud
```

With `bash` or `ksh93`, you'd have to do something convoluted like:

```
VOWEL=( a e i o u )
CONS=( b c d )
qVOWEL=$(printf %q, "${VOWEL[@]}")
qCONS=$(printf %q, "${CONS[@]}")
eval "echo {${qVOWEL%,}}{${qCONS%,}}"
```

Comment: Just one more reason to use zsh.

Comment: Are you certain that there's no more direct way to do it in bash? Or do you just suspect that it is so?

Comment: @Catskul, no, I strongly doubt it but I'm not certain, I'm even less certain for ksh93 where a number of features are not documented. You may want to leave the question open for a while. I'm pretty sure you can't do it with brace expansion without another level of evaluation (with `eval` or `.`) though.

Comment: `eval "echo {$(printf ',%s' "${CONS[@]}" "${VOWEL[@]}" | tail -c+2)}"` (Not working for single element though.)

Answer (score 2):

Fun, but probably not the best.

```
temparr=( b{a,e,i,o,u} c{a,e,i,o,u} d{a,e,i,o,u} )
echo "${temparr[@]}"
```

Comment: True, but requires repeating the vowels, which isn't implied from the question (assigning a static list to CONS and VOWEL each).